# Applying for Schengen visa from India for a person working in USA

Tags: visas, schengen, france, indian-citizens

I'm working in the USA on a H1B visa and am currently in India on vacation. On my flight back to the US, I want to visit Paris for a couple of days. Is it possible for me to apply for the Schengen VISA from the consulate in India, which is my country of citizenship. I've been working in the US for over 2 years now.

Comment: You're an Indian citizen, in India, and wondering if you can apply for a Schengen visa in India? Why wouldn't you be able to? That's the normal method...

Comment: I know it seems obvious that I should be able apply. After a call to the French Embassy here however it seems that I cannot apply. They mentioned that I need to have been staying in India for 6 months to apply here. I'll try adding the website mentioned by Vagish and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply in India. See the FAQ here: http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/india/more_info/faq/schengen_visa_en.htm#faq5

However you may have to explain to the embassy you are applying to about the reason you are applying from India rather than the USA where you currently reside.

Comment: Thanks for the link Vagish. I had seen this snippet in some other website as well and according to this it seems like I should be able to apply, however when I called the French Embassy, the customer care representative told me that there is a requirement that I should have been staying in India for over 6 months if I am to apply here. I'll try quoting this info.

Comment: Try and explain the circumstance to the customer care representative. Are you going to be in France the majority of the time? Other embassies may be more lenient. But you can only use them if you are entering the zone in that country or that is the country is the main one you are staying in.

Answer (score 0):

No, in principle you should apply at your place of residence. In practice, many consulates might accept applications from citizens without asking for any other evidence that you are in fact a resident or or make an exception depending on your circumstances but technically that's the rule.